# what is db.collection.stats() equivalent in mongodb npm?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb npm as mongoDb driver in node.js

Is there a way to do

```
 db.collection.stats()
```

similar to what we can do in mongo Shell

Comment: The mongodb native driver documentation can be found here: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/contents.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get db statistics you can use stats with callback like

```
stats([options], callback)
```

Example :

```
var db = new Db('test', new Server('locahost', 27017));

db.open(function(err, db) {
 //Open connection

  db.stats(function(err, stats) {
    // second parameter stats contains the result from  stats 
    db.close();
  })
});
```